# How do I create a SQLAlchemy model with two database engines?

Tags: python, database, orm, sqlalchemy

I'm currently using declarative_base function to generate a base for me that gets inherented in my SQLAlchemy base models.

I'm trying to pass two database settings. One for read, and one for write.

How do I implement multiple databases connections in SQLAlchmey ORM?

I'm trying to do something like that:

```
Base = sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base(bind=[<list of engines])


class Foo(base):
    name = Column(String)

    def save(self):
        ... # save logic using the first database.
    def filter_by(self):
        ... # filter logic using the second database.
```

Comment: Just a thought. Have not tested but what if you create two declarative base and your model inherits both. Just curious

Comment: I went with creating another declarative base that's only used for that database.